# Cannot submit my data to server by XHR requests in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have made a chrome extension that makes some XHR requests. This extension pulls some data from some sites and then passes all those data to my server. The problem is that I am able to get the data (i.e I can make XHR calls) but when I try to submit the data to server, it gives the following error : "Failed to load resource"

Now I have checked that I have proper permissions for XHR requests because:
1) Sometimes the code works fine.
2) I can make ajax calls because I am getting data from other servers. Its just that I cannot submit data to my server.

What might be wrong ??
1 possible solution I found was that ad-block is blocking my request but disabling that didn't made a difference.

Here is part of manifest file for reference:

```
  "permissions": [
"http://*.facebook.com/*",
"https://*.facebook.com/*",
"http://*.lersais.exp.sis.pitt.edu/frivacy/*",
"https://*.lersais.exp.sis.pitt.edu/frivacy/*",
"tabs"]
```

"lersais" is the server where I want to put my data.

here is the code that I am using to send data to this "lersais" server:

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://lersais.exp.sis.pitt.edu/frivacy/save-settings.php",
type: "POST",
data: {jsondata: JSON.stringify(settings)},
dataType: "text"
    }).done( function(response){
console.log("data was successfully sent");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...my server was not supporting https...because for this you have to have certificate and all...this is why the code was not working. I used "http" instead of "https" and the code works... :)

Hope this helps someone.